# Why do I have to authenticate again with password after having logged in with fingerprint?

Tags: login, password, security, authentication, fingerprint-reader

The fingerprint reader on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th works well on stock Ubuntu 20.04. I use it for all day to day logins without problems. However, after having logged in with my fingerprint to my user account (after restart), I get a pop-up dialog asking me to authenticate with my password. Why isn't the fingerprint login enough when I log into my user account? Can I somehow set it to only ask for fingerprint in this instance also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fingerprint reader for login never decodes your password ring, which would be necessary for some other things like email.  The password ring is encoded with your password, so that's what's needed for the decode.  Unfortunately, that makes fingerprint login less useful than you might like.

Comment: Thank you for that. You are right, makes fingerprint user account login less useful. Works well for root access and application installations.